# TypeError: request.callback is not a function using Node JS and SQLServer Tedious

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, tedious

I'm working on a project in NodeJS, this project takes data from a JSON file (I downloaded `node-fetch` for this) then I put them into an object to then send all the objects into an array and after that save it to a SQLServer DB, the issue that I'm having is that I cannot make it work, I followed what I watched in [NodeJS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15) but I get this error when I type `node app2.mjs`:

```
node app2.mjs
Successful connection
***:\***\***\***\***\***\***\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1700
request.callback(error);
^
TypeError: request.callback is not a function
at ***:\***\***\***\***\***\***\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1700:17
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
PS ***:\***\***\***\***\***\project>
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "msnodesqlv8": "^2.4.3",
    "mssql": "^7.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "tedious": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

and this is my `app2.mjs` :

```
import { Connection } from "tedious";
var lstValid = [];

var config = {
  // Connection stuff (This works)
};

var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on("connect", function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Failed to connect!!! ", err);
  } else {
    // If no error, then good to go...
    console.log("Successful connection");
    executeStatement();
  }
});

connection.connect();

const api_key = process.env.apikey;

async function calcWeather() {
  const info = await fetch("../json/data.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  for (var i in info) {
    const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina;
    const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
    const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
    const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    fetch(base)
      .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var myObject = {
          Id_Oficina: _idOficina,
          Humedad: data.main.humidity,
          Nubes: data.clouds.all,
          Sensacion: data.main.feels_like,
          Temperatura: data.main.temp,
          Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
        };
        // validation and saving data to array
        if (myObject.Temperatura < 99)
          lstValid.push(myObject);
      });
  }
}

import { Request } from "tedious"; 
import { TYPES } from "tedious";   

function executeStatement() {
  calcWeather();
  for (var m = 0; m <= 5 /*lstValid.length*/; m++) {
    const RequestB = new Request(
      "EXEC USP_BI_CSL_insert_reg_RegistroTemperaturaXidOdicina @IdOficina, @Humedad, @Nubes, @Sensacion, @Temperatura, @Descripcion",
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't insert data: " + err);
        }
      }
    );
    RequestB.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].myObject.Id_Oficina);
    RequestB.addParameter("Humedad", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].myObject.Humedad);
    RequestB.addParameter("Nubes", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].myObject.Nubes);
    RequestB.addParameter("Sensacion", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].myObject.Sensacion);
    RequestB.addParameter("Temperatura", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].myObject.Temperatura);
    RequestB.addParameter("Descripcion", TYPES.VarChar, lstValid[m].myObject.Descripcion);

    RequestB.on("row", function (columns) {
      columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
          console.log("NULL");
        } else {
          console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
        }
      });
    });

    connection.execSql(Request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was, I was sending `connection.execSql(Request);` as it should have been `connection.execSql(RequestB);` because that's how I named my constant variable of the new request:

```
const RequestB = new Request(
    "EXEC USP_BI_CSL_insert_reg_RegistroTemperaturaXidOdicina @IdOficina, @Humedad, @Nubes, @Sensacion, @Temperatura, @Descripcion",
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Couldn't insert data: " + err);
        }
    }
);
```