# How can I insert attributes of an object from an array of objects into SQLServer using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, tedious

I made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037752/typeerror-request-callback-is-not-a-function-using-node-js-and-sqlserver-tediou) a minutes ago that I could solve but now I'm having another problem with my code, I have an array of objects `lstValid[]`and I need each object to be inserted into a table (using a SP) and I though of a way to made it reading documentation but it's not working, maybe it's just a fool mistake but I don't know how to solve it, my mistake is

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Id_Oficina')`

as you can see, it executes my SP but it says the attribute `Id_Oficina` is undefined, do you know why is undefined? why is it reading the array but not the attribute?

Here is the function where I create the objects and insert them into the array:

```
async function calcWeather() {
  const info = await fetch("../json/data.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  for (var i in info) {
    const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina;
    const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
    const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
    const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    fetch(base)
      .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var myObject = {
          Id_Oficina: _idOficina,
          Humedad: data.main.humidity,
          Nubes: data.clouds.all,
          Sensacion: data.main.feels_like,
          Temperatura: data.main.temp,
          Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
        };
        // validation and saving data to array
        if (myObject.Temperatura < 99)
          lstValid.push(myObject);
      });
  }
}
```

and here's the function where I insert into DB:

```
import { Request } from "tedious";
import { TYPES } from "tedious";  

function executeStatement() {
  calcWeather();
  for (var m = 0; m >= lstValid.length; m++) {
    const request = new Request(
      "EXEC USP_BI_CSL_insert_reg_RegistroTemperaturaXidOdicina @IdOficina, @Humedad, @Nubes, @Sensacion, @Temperatura, @Descripcion",
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't insert data: " + err);
        }
      }
    );

    request.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Id_Oficina);
    request.addParameter("Humedad", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Humedad);
    request.addParameter("Nubes", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Nubes);
    request.addParameter("Sensacion", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].Sensacion);
    request.addParameter("Temperatura", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].Temperatura);
    request.addParameter("Descripcion", TYPES.VarChar, lstValid[m].Descripcion);

    request.on("row", function (columns) {
      columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
          console.log("NULL");
        } else {
          console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
        }
      });
    });

    connection.execSql(request); // connection.execSql(RequestB);??
  }
  request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
    connection.close();
  }); 
}
```

I also tried sending them this way but doesn't work either:

```
 request.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].myObject.Id_Oficina);
```

Comment: Which is the exact line where the error happens?

Comment: @LajosArpad in the line where I send the attribute of the object in the array, it's ```request.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Id_Oficina);```

Comment: What's the value of `lstValid[m]`? Can you console.log it or debug it?

Comment: What's the value of `lstValid.length` when you enter the loop? If `lstValid.length` is `0` then `lstValid[0]` is going to return `undefined`.

Comment: sorry for answering so late, I didn't have access to my job's pc, @AlwaysLearning @Lajos Arpad
  the ```lstValid.length``` is ```0```, can you help me to solve it?

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry for answering so late, I didn't have access to my job's pc, the ```lstValid.length``` is ```0```, can you help me to solve it?

Comment: @MartínJF if `isValid.length` was 0, then `isValid[m]` is `undefined` and the error is something we can expect. I have elaborated on this in my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a bad condition at the line of

```
for (var m = 0; m >= lstValid.length; m++) {
```

This loop initializes `m` with 0 and increments it while it's greater or equal with the number of elements `lstValid` has. Since Javascript is a 0-indexed language, `lstValid.length` is always an invalid index. Valid indexes fulfill this formula

**0 <= valid index < lstValid.length**

Since your condition checks whether the index is invalid and only then iterates the loop, it will error out at the first iteration if `lstValid` is empty and it will not execute at all when `lstValid` is not empty.

## Fix

```
for (var m = 0; m < lstValid.length; m++) {
```

## Explanation

Your error came from the fact that `lstValid.length` was 0, `m` was 0 and your code attempted to process member fields of the first element of an empty array. Since there was no first element in the speicifc case, it errored out.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation mate, but I dont really get why it keeps telling me in my ```console.log``` the lenght is still ```0``` as it should be all the objects I have in my array :c

Comment: Got it, now I get ```ReferenceError: fetch is not defined``` that's why no object is entering the array, right?

Comment: @MartínJF you are welcome! We need to step-by-step debug your code and see where it fails to meet your expectations. You have the call of `await fetch("../json/data.json")` as the very first operation of your `calcWeather` function. If you add `console.log(info)` just before the line of `for (var i in info) {` what do you see?

Comment: @MartínJF you are correct!

Comment: The ```console.log(info)``` before ```(var i in info)``` doesn't do nothing :c

Comment: @MartínJF yes, I know this in light of your penultimate comment, but when I was typing it, I was not yet aware that `fetch` is undefined`.

Comment: @MartínJF It appears that we have fixed your current issue with the incorrect loop, but we have another issue, namely that `fetch` is undefined. You are either trying to call it before it's loaded, or missing a `script` tag or a `require` command. You may want to ask another question that deals with this issue. As about our current problem, if the problem you have asked about that manifested in erroring out when the array is empty has been answered, then you can consider accepting this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sure mate, thanks for your time, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @MartínJF happy to help. If you have another question, then when you complete writing it, you may want to leave a comment here. I will probably look into it tomorrow. If you manage to solve your current issue on your own, then let me know about the good news.

Comment: sure, thanks mate I just asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70067812/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-json-referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined) thanks again :)