# How can I get data from a JSON? ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sql-server, tedious

I'm currently working in a project that takes data from a JSON (`data.json`) and then inserts it into a constant variable `` const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`; `` with this data, I get more data to create a hundred objects, then I insert them into an array and I save the attributes to a DB in sqlserver.
I use a `for` for reading the whole array of objects and insert the attributes into the DB, the issue I'm having is that my array `lstValid` is getting none objects, and when I run my project I get

```
const info = await fetch("../json/data.json").then(function (response) {
               ^
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I'm expecting to know how can I fix this issue to insert the objects into my array and then be able to insert it into my DB, I have already install `"node-fetch": "^3.1.0",`

here is my package,json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "msnodesqlv8": "^2.4.3",
    "mssql": "^7.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "tedious": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

and here's my `app2.mjs`

```
import { Connection } from "tedious"; 
var lstValid = [];

var config = {
  // connection stuff (works)
};

var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on("connect", function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Failed to connect!!! ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Successful connection");
    executeStatement();
  }
});

connection.connect();

const api_key = process.env.apikey;

async function calcWeather() {
  const info = await fetch("../json/data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });

  for (var i in info) {
    const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina;
    const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
    const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
    const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    fetch(base)
      .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var myObject = {
          Id_Oficina: _idOficina,
          Humedad: data.main.humidity,
          Nubes: data.clouds.all,
          Sensacion: data.main.feels_like,
          Temperatura: data.main.temp,
          Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
        };
        // validation and saving data to array
        if (myObject.Temperatura < 99) {
          lstValid.push(myObject);
        }
      });
  }
}

import { Request } from "tedious"; // var Request = require("tedious").Request;
import { TYPES } from "tedious"; // var TYPES = require("tedious").TYPES;

function executeStatement() {
  calcWeather();
  console.log(lstValid.length);
  for (var m = 0; m < lstValid.length; m++) {
    const request = new Request(
      "EXEC INSERT_SP @IdOficina, @Humedad, @Nubes, @Sensacion, @Temperatura, @Descripcion",
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't insert data: " + err);
        }
      }
    );
    request.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Id_Oficina);
    request.addParameter("Humedad", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Humedad);
    request.addParameter("Nubes", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m].Nubes);
    request.addParameter("Sensacion", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].Sensacion);
    request.addParameter("Temperatura", TYPES.Float, lstValid[m].Temperatura);
    request.addParameter("Descripcion", TYPES.VarChar, lstValid[m].Descripcion);
    request.on("row", function (columns) {
      columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
          console.log("NULL");
        } else {
          console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
        }
      });
    });
    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
      connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
  }
}
```

I'm following [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: did you add `import fetch from 'node-fetch';` at start of your script?

Comment: That was the issue, lol, thanks mate :) @michalpavlik

Comment: Michal, you might want to convert your comment into an answer so future visitors having a similar issue will know that 1. There is a solution 2. What the solution is with a single glance.